# Find probablity of winning

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The Celtics and the Lakers are set to play a playoff series of $n$ basketball games, where $n$ is odd. The Celtics have a probability $p$ of winning any game, independent of other games.

1. Find the values of $p$ for which $n=5$ is better for the Celtics than
   $n=3$.
2. Generalise part (1), i.e., for any $k>0$, find the values for $p$
   for which $n= 2k+1$ is better for Celtics than $n=2k-1$.

I have tried that for part 1 as follows:

$\binom{3}{2}p^2(1-p)+\binom{3}{3}p^3 < \binom{5}{3}p^3(1-p)^2+\binom{5}{4}p^4(1-p)+\binom{5}{5}p^5$

how to solve this equation?

how to generalize part 2?

Comment: What happens when you expand your expression (and factor out $p^2$)?  Note that $p=1$ is likely to be a zero of the resulting cubic

Answer (score 2):

Say that teams play $n=2k+1$ games. After those, a team can win by 1-game margin or 3-game or more margin. In the latter case, adding 2 more games won't change the result. In the former, adding two more games can switch the result. To calculate if this brings an advantage to a team, we need to calculate if there are more times that a team wins the series  being 1 game behind after $n$ games than the times that the team loses the series  being 1 game ahead after $n$ games. In formula:

$$
P(\text{1 behind})P(\text{win the following 2}) > P(\text{1 ahead})P(\text{lose the following two})
$$

$$
\binom{2k+1}{k} p^k (1-p)^{k+1} p^2 > \binom{2k+1}{k+1} p^{k+1}(1-p)^k (1-p)^2
$$

which easily leads to the obvious $\frac{1}{2}<p<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Think differently.

If you have the sequence of wins and losses, e.g. $WLLWWLW$, you need to improve your chances by adding two new outcomes.

I think this solves both problems, with $p > 0.5$

Comment: You probably need to avoid $p=1$, as there is no improvement on perfection

Comment: hmm, maybe it is not correct after all, suppose you have 70% chance, and adding 2 events at 60% may not be an improvement.